# increase clarity of a graph

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using jfreechart for plotting graphs. The problem is that if have more entries on the X-axis, then the X-axis parameters are not visible. How should I solve that?

Comment: A picture would be worth 1000 words here.  Can you post a screen shot?  :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the scale of the graph until you can see the parameters.